# PHP: "Cannot redeclare class ..." even if I change the name of the class

Tags: php

I have downloaded the [PayPal API (SOAP) for PHP](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_PHP_SOAP_SDK.zip).

I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
>   SOAP_Client in
>   /home/me/app1/plugins/mbpPlatformFrontendPlugin/lib/paypal/PayPal/SOAP/Client.php
>   on line 83

**The strange thing is:** if I change the name of the class to what ever else, for example SOAP_Client_foo, I get

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
>   SOAP_Client_foo in
>   /home/me/app1/plugins/mbpPlatformFrontendPlugin/lib/paypal/PayPal/SOAP/Client.php
>   on line 83

Any idea?

```
<?php
//
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | PHP Version 4                                                        |
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | Copyright (c) 1997-2003 The PHP Group                                |
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | This source file is subject to version 2.02 of the PHP license,      |
// | that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE, and is        |
// | available at through the world-wide-web at                           |
// | http://www.php.net/license/2_02.txt.                                 |
// | If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license and are unable to   |
// | obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send a note to          |
// | license@php.net so we can mail you a copy immediately.               |
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | Authors: Shane Caraveo <Shane@Caraveo.com>   Port to PEAR and more   |
// | Authors: Dietrich Ayala <dietrich@ganx4.com> Original Author         |
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
//
// $Id: Client.php,v 1.1.1.1 2006/02/19 08:15:20 dennis Exp $
//

//require_once 'PayPal/SOAP/Value.php';
//require_once 'PayPal/SOAP/Base.php';
//require_once 'PayPal/SOAP/Transport.php';
//require_once 'PayPal/SOAP/WSDL.php';
//require_once 'PayPal/SOAP/Fault.php';
//require_once 'PayPal/SOAP/Parser.php';
//require_once 'PayPal/SOAP/PatternReplace.php';

// Arnaud: the following code was taken from DataObject
// and adapted to suit

// this will be horrifically slow!!!!
// NOTE: Overload SEGFAULTS ON PHP4 + Zend Optimizer
// these two are BC/FC handlers for call in PHP4/5

if (!class_exists('SOAP_Client_Overload')) {
    if (substr(phpversion(), 0, 1) == 5) {
        class SOAP_Client_Overload extends SOAP_Base
        {
            function __call($method, $args)
            {
                $return = null;
                $this->_call($method, $args, $return);
                return $return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (!function_exists('clone')) {
            eval('function clone($t) { return $t; }');
        }
        eval('
            class SOAP_Client_Overload extends SOAP_Base
            {
                function __call($method, $args, &$return)
                {
                    return $this->_call($method, $args, $return);
                }
            }');
    }
}

/**
 * SOAP Client Class
 *
 * This class is the main interface for making soap requests.
 *
 * basic usage:
 *   $soapclient = new SOAP_Client( string path [ , boolean wsdl] );
 *   echo $soapclient->call( string methodname [ , array parameters] );
 *
 * Originally based on SOAPx4 by Dietrich Ayala
 * http://dietrich.ganx4.com/soapx4
 *
 * @access   public
 * @package  SOAP::Client
 * @author   Shane Caraveo <shane@php.net> Conversion to PEAR and updates
 * @author   Stig Bakken <ssb@fast.no> Conversion to PEAR
 * @author   Dietrich Ayala <dietrich@ganx4.com> Original Author
 */
class SOAP_Client extends SOAP_Client_Overload
{
    /**
     * Communication endpoint.
     *
     * Currently the following transport formats are supported:
     *  - HTTP
     *  - SMTP
     *
     * Example endpoints:
     *   http://www.example.com/soap/server.php
     *   https://www.example.com/soap/server.php
     *   mailto:soap@example.com
     *
     * @var  string
     * @see  SOAP_Client()
     */
    public $_endpoint = '';

    /**
     * portname
     *
     * @var string contains the SOAP PORT name that is used by the client
     */
    public $_portName = '';

    /**
     * Endpoint type
     *
     * @var  string  e.g. wdsl
     */
    public $__endpointType = '';

    /**
     * wire
     *
     * @var  string  contains outoing and incoming data stream for debugging.
     */
    public $xml; // contains the received xml
    public $wire;
    public $__last_request = null;
    public $__last_response = null;

    /**
     * Options
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $__options = array('trace'=>0);

    /**
     * encoding
     *
     * @var  string  Contains the character encoding used for XML parser, etc.
     */
    public $_encoding = SOAP_DEFAULT_ENCODING;

    /**
     * headersOut
     *
     * @var  array  contains an array of SOAP_Headers that we are sending
     */
    public $headersOut = null;

    /**
     * headersOut
     *
     * @var  array  contains an array headers we recieved back in the response
     */
    public $headersIn = null;

    /**
     * __proxy_params
     *
     * @var  array  contains options for HTTP_Request class (see HTTP/Request.php)
     */
    public $__proxy_params = array();

    public $_soap_transport = null;

    /**
     * SOAP_Client constructor
     *
     * @param string endpoint (URL)
     * @param boolean wsdl (true if endpoint is a wsdl file)
     * @param string portName
     * @param array  contains options for HTTP_Request class (see HTTP/Request.php)
     * @access public
     */
    function SOAP_Client($endpoint, $wsdl = false, $portName = false, $proxy_params=array())
    {
        parent::SOAP_Base('Client');
        $this->_endpoint = $endpoint;
        $this->_portName = $portName;
        $this->__proxy_params = $proxy_params;

        $wsdl = $wsdl ? $wsdl : strcasecmp('wsdl', substr($endpoint, strlen($endpoint) - 4)) == 0;

        // make values
        if ($wsdl) {
            $this->__endpointType = 'wsdl';
            // instantiate wsdl class
            $this->_wsdl =  new SOAP_WSDL($this->_endpoint, $this->__proxy_params);
            if ($this->_wsdl->fault) {
                $this->_raiseSoapFault($this->_wsdl->fault);
            }
        }
    }

    function _reset()
    {
        $this->xml = null;
        $this->wire = null;
        $this->__last_request = null;
        $this->__last_response = null;
        $this->headersIn = null;
        $this->headersOut = null;
    }

    /**
     * setEncoding
     *
     * set the character encoding, limited to 'UTF-8', 'US_ASCII' and 'ISO-8859-1'
     *
     * @param string encoding
     * @return mixed returns null or SOAP_Fault
     * @access public
     */
    function setEncoding($encoding)
    {
        if (in_array($encoding, $this->_encodings)) {
            $this->_encoding = $encoding;
            return null;
        }
        return $this->_raiseSoapFault('Invalid Encoding');
    }

    /**
     * addHeader
     *
     * To add headers to the envelop, you use this function, sending it a
     * SOAP_Header class instance.
     *
     * @param SOAP_Header a soap value to send as a header
     * @access public
     */
    function addHeader(&$soap_value)
    {
        # add a new header to the message
        if (is_a($soap_value,'soap_header')) {
            $this->headersOut[] =& $soap_value;
        } else if (gettype($soap_value) == 'array') {
            // name, value, namespace, mustunderstand, actor
            $this->headersOut[] =  new SOAP_Header($soap_value[0], null, $soap_value[1], $soap_value[2], $soap_value[3]);;
        } else {
            $this->_raiseSoapFault("Don't understand the header info you provided.  Must be array or SOAP_Header.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * SOAP_Client::call
     *
     * the namespace parameter is overloaded to accept an array of
     * options that can contain data necessary for various transports
     * if it is used as an array, it MAY contain a namespace value and a
     * soapaction value.  If it is overloaded, the soapaction parameter is
     * ignored and MUST be placed in the options array.  This is done
     * to provide backwards compatibility with current clients, but
     * may be removed in the future.
     *
     * @param string method
     * @param array  params
     * @param array options (hash with namespace, soapaction, timeout, from, subject, etc.)
     *
     * The options parameter can have a variety of values added.  The currently supported
     * values are:
     *   namespace
     *   soapaction
     *   timeout (http socket timeout)
     *   from (smtp)
     *   transfer-encoding (smtp, sets the Content-Transfer-Encoding header)
     *   subject (smtp, subject header)
     *   headers (smtp, array-hash of extra smtp headers)
     *
     * @return array of results
     * @access public
     */
    function &call($method, &$params, $namespace = false, $soapAction = false)
    {
        $this->headersIn = null;
        $this->__last_request = null;
        $this->__last_response = null;
        $this->wire = null;
        $this->xml = null;

        $soap_data =& $this->__generate($method, $params, $namespace, $soapAction);
        if (PEAR::isError($soap_data)) {
            return $this->_raiseSoapFault($soap_data);
        }

        // __generate may have changed the endpoint if the wsdl has more
        // than one service, so we need to see if we need to generate
        // a new transport to hook to a different URI.  Since the transport
        // protocol can also change, we need to get an entirely new object,
        // though this could probably be optimized.
        if (!$this->_soap_transport || $this->_endpoint != $this->_soap_transport->url) {
            $this->_soap_transport =& SOAP_Transport::getTransport($this->_endpoint);
            if (PEAR::isError($this->_soap_transport)) {
                $fault =& $this->_soap_transport;
                $this->_soap_transport = null;
                return $this->_raiseSoapFault($fault);
            }
        }
        $this->_soap_transport->encoding = $this->_encoding;

        // Send the message.
        $transport_options = array_merge_recursive($this->__proxy_params, $this->__options);

      // This is to replace "_" by "-" since wsdl has "-" and not "_"   (see NOTE in Readme.html)
        if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/PatternReplace.php')){
                 $soap_data =  underscore_replace($soap_data);
        }

        $this->xml =& $this->_soap_transport->send($soap_data, $transport_options);

        // Save the wire information for debugging.
        if ($this->__options['trace'] > 0) {
            $this->__last_request =& $this->_soap_transport->outgoing_payload;
            $this->__last_response =& $this->_soap_transport->incoming_payload;
            $this->wire =& $this->__get_wire();
        }
        if ($this->_soap_transport->fault) {
            return $this->_raiseSoapFault($this->xml);
        }

        $this->__attachments =& $this->_soap_transport->attachments;
        $this->__result_encoding = $this->_soap_transport->result_encoding;

        if (isset($this->__options['result']) && $this->__options['result'] != 'parse') {
            return $this->xml;
        }

        return $this->__parse($this->xml, $this->__result_encoding, $this->__attachments);
    }

    /**
     * Sets option to use with the transports layers.
     *
     * An example of such use is
     * $soapclient->setOpt('curl', CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1)
     * to pass a specific option to when using an SSL connection.
     *
     * @access public
     * @param  string  $category  category to which the option applies
     * @param  string  $option    option name
     * @param  string  $value     option value
     * @return void
     */
    function setOpt($category, $option, $value = null)
    {
        if (!is_null($value)) {
            if (!isset($this->__options[$category])) {
                $this->__options[$category] = array();
            }
            $this->__options[$category][$option] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->__options[$category] = $option;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Overload extension support
     * if the overload extension is loaded, you can call the client class
     * with a soap method name
     * $soap = new SOAP_Client(....);
     * $value = $soap->getStockQuote('MSFT');
     *
     * @param string method
     * @param array  args
     * @param string retur_value
     *
     * @return boolean
     * @access public
     */
    function _call($method, $args, &$return_value)
    {
        // XXX overloading lowercases the method name, we
        // need to look into the wsdl and try to find
        // the correct method name to get the correct
        // case for the call.
        if ($this->_wsdl) {
            $this->_wsdl->matchMethod($method);
        }

        $return_value =& $this->call($method, $args);
        return true;
    }

    function &__getlastrequest()
    {
        return $this->__last_request;
    }

    function &__getlastresponse()
    {
        return $this->__last_response;
    }

    function __use($use)
    {
        $this->__options['use'] = $use;
    }

    function __style($style)
    {
        $this->__options['style'] = $style;
    }

    function __trace($level)
    {
        $this->__options['trace'] = $level;
    }

    function &__generate($method, &$params, $namespace = false, $soapAction = false)
    {
        $this->fault = null;
        $this->__options['input']='parse';
        $this->__options['result']='parse';
        $this->__options['parameters'] = false;
        if ($params && gettype($params) != 'array') {
            $params = array($params);
        }
        if (gettype($namespace) == 'array') {
            foreach ($namespace as $optname => $opt) {
                $this->__options[strtolower($optname)] = $opt;
            }
            if (isset($this->__options['namespace'])) {
                $namespace = $this->__options['namespace'];
            } else {
                $namespace = false;
            }
        } else {
            // we'll place soapaction into our array for usage in the transport
            $this->__options['soapaction'] = $soapAction;
            $this->__options['namespace'] = $namespace;
        }

        if ($this->__endpointType == 'wsdl') {
            $this->_setSchemaVersion($this->_wsdl->xsd);
            // get portName
            if (!$this->_portName) {
                $this->_portName = $this->_wsdl->getPortName($method);
            }
            if (PEAR::isError($this->_portName)) {
                return $this->_raiseSoapFault($this->_portName);
            }

            // get endpoint
            $this->_endpoint = $this->_wsdl->getEndpoint($this->_portName);
            if (PEAR::isError($this->_endpoint)) {
                return $this->_raiseSoapFault($this->_endpoint);
            }

            // get operation data
            $opData = $this->_wsdl->getOperationData($this->_portName, $method);

            if (PEAR::isError($opData)) {
                return $this->_raiseSoapFault($opData);
            }
            $namespace = $opData['namespace'];
            $this->__options['style'] = $opData['style'];
            $this->__options['use'] = $opData['input']['use'];
            $this->__options['soapaction'] = $opData['soapAction'];

            // set input params
            if ($this->__options['input'] == 'parse') {
                $this->__options['parameters'] = $opData['parameters'];
                $nparams = array();
                if (isset($opData['input']['parts']) && count($opData['input']['parts']) > 0) {
                    $i = 0;
                    reset($params);
                    foreach ($opData['input']['parts'] as $name => $part) {
                        $xmlns = '';
                        $attrs = array();
                        // is the name actually a complex type?
                        if (isset($part['element'])) {
                            $xmlns = $this->_wsdl->namespaces[$part['namespace']];
                            $part = $this->_wsdl->elements[$part['namespace']][$part['type']];
                            $name = $part['name'];
                        }
                        if (array_key_exists($name, $params) ||
                            $this->_wsdl->getDataHandler($name, $part['namespace'])) {
                            $nparams[$name] =& $params[$name];
                        } else {
                            // we now force an associative array for
                            // parameters if using wsdl.
                            return $this->_raiseSoapFault("The named parameter $name is not in the call parameters.");
                        }
                        if (gettype($nparams[$name]) != 'object' ||
                            !is_a($nparams[$name],'soap_value')) {
                            // type is a qname likely, split it apart, and get the type namespace from wsdl
                            $qname =  new QName($part['type']);
                            if ($qname->ns) {
                                $type_namespace = $this->_wsdl->namespaces[$qname->ns];
                            } else if (isset($part['namespace'])) {
                                $type_namespace = $this->_wsdl->namespaces[$part['namespace']];
                            } else {
                                $type_namespace = null;
                            }
                            $qname->namespace = $type_namespace;
                            $type = $qname->name;
                            $pqname = $name;
                            if ($xmlns) {
                                $pqname = '{' . $xmlns . '}' . $name;
                            }
                            $nparams[$name] =  new SOAP_Value($pqname, $qname->fqn(), $nparams[$name], $attrs);
                        } else {
                            // wsdl fixups to the soap value.
                        }
                    }
                }
                $params =& $nparams;
                unset($nparams);
            }
        } else {
            $this->_setSchemaVersion(SOAP_XML_SCHEMA_VERSION);
        }

        // serialize the message.
        $this->_section5 = (isset($this->__options['use']) && $this->__options['use'] == 'literal');

        if (!isset($this->__options['style']) || $this->__options['style'] == 'rpc') {
            $this->__options['style'] = 'rpc';
            $this->docparams = true;
            $mqname =  new QName($method, $namespace);
            $methodValue =  new SOAP_Value($mqname->fqn(), 'Struct', $params);
            $soap_msg =& $this->_makeEnvelope($methodValue, $this->headersOut, $this->_encoding, $this->__options);
        } else {
            if (!$params) {
                $mqname =  new QName($method, $namespace);
                $mynull = null;
                $params =  new SOAP_Value($mqname->fqn(), 'Struct', $mynull);
            } elseif ($this->__options['input'] == 'parse') {
                if (is_array($params)) {
                    $nparams = array();
                    $keys = array_keys($params);
                    foreach ($keys as $k) {
                        if (gettype($params[$k]) != 'object') {
                            $nparams[] =  new SOAP_Value($k, false, $params[$k]);
                        } else {
                            $nparams[] =& $params[$k];
                        }
                    }
                    $params =& $nparams;
                }
                if ($this->__options['parameters']) {
                    $mqname =  new QName($method, $namespace);
                    $params =  new SOAP_Value($mqname->fqn(), 'Struct', $params);
                }
            }
            $soap_msg =& $this->_makeEnvelope($params, $this->headersOut, $this->_encoding, $this->__options);
        }
        unset($this->headersOut);

        if (PEAR::isError($soap_msg)) {
            return $this->_raiseSoapFault($soap_msg);
        }

        // handle Mime or DIME encoding
        // XXX DIME Encoding should move to the transport, do it here for now
        // and for ease of getting it done
        if (count($this->__attachments)) {
            if ((isset($this->__options['attachments']) && $this->__options['attachments'] == 'Mime') || isset($this->__options['Mime'])) {
                $soap_msg =& $this->_makeMimeMessage($soap_msg, $this->_encoding);
            } else {
                // default is dime
                $soap_msg =& $this->_makeDIMEMessage($soap_msg, $this->_encoding);
                $this->__options['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/dime';
            }
            if (PEAR::isError($soap_msg)) {
                return $this->_raiseSoapFault($soap_msg);
            }
        }

        // instantiate client
        if (is_array($soap_msg)) {
            $soap_data =& $soap_msg['body'];
            if (count($soap_msg['headers'])) {
                if (isset($this->__options['headers'])) {
                    $this->__options['headers'] = array_merge($this->__options['headers'], $soap_msg['headers']);
                } else {
                    $this->__options['headers'] = $soap_msg['headers'];
                }
            }
        } else {
            $soap_data =& $soap_msg;
        }
        return $soap_data;
    }

    function &__parse(&$response, $encoding, &$attachments)
    {
        // parse the response
        $response =  new SOAP_Parser($response, $encoding, $attachments);
        if ($response->fault) {
            return $this->_raiseSoapFault($response->fault);
        }
        // return array of parameters
        $return =& $response->getResponse();
        $headers =& $response->getHeaders();
        if ($headers) {
            $this->headersIn =& $this->__decodeResponse($headers, false);
        }
        return $this->__decodeResponse($return);
    }

    function &__decodeResponse(&$response, $shift = true)
    {
        if (!$response) {
            return null;
        }
        // Check for valid response.
        if (PEAR::isError($response)) {
            return $this->_raiseSoapFault($response);
        } elseif (!is_a($response, 'soap_value')) {
            return $this->_raiseSoapFault("didn't get SOAP_Value object back from client");
        }

        // Decode to native php datatype.
        $returnArray =& $this->_decode($response);

        // Fault?
        if (PEAR::isError($returnArray)) {
            return $this->_raiseSoapFault($returnArray);
        }
        if (is_object($returnArray) && strcasecmp(get_class($returnArray),'stdClass') == 0) {
            $returnArray = get_object_vars($returnArray);
        }
        if (is_array($returnArray)) {
            if (isset($returnArray['faultcode']) || isset($returnArray['SOAP-ENV:faultcode'])) {
                $faultcode = $faultstring = $faultdetail = $faultactor = '';
                foreach ($returnArray as $k => $v) {
                    if (stristr($k, 'faultcode')) $faultcode = $v;
                    if (stristr($k, 'faultstring')) $faultstring = $v;
                    if (stristr($k, 'detail')) $faultdetail = $v;
                    if (stristr($k, 'faultactor')) $faultactor = $v;
                }
                return $this->_raiseSoapFault($faultstring, $faultdetail, $faultactor, $faultcode);
            }
            // Return array of return values.
            if ($shift && count($returnArray) == 1) {
                return array_shift($returnArray);
            }
            return $returnArray;
        }
        return $returnArray;
    }

    function __get_wire()
    {
        if ($this->__options['trace'] > 0 && ($this->__last_request || $this->__last_response)) {
            return "OUTGOING:\n\n".
            $this->__last_request.
            "\n\nINCOMING\n\n".
            preg_replace("/></",">\r\n<", $this->__last_response);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**:

I have typed `...paypal$ grep -R 'Client.php' *`, and I'm getting this:

```
PayPal/CallerServices.php://require_once 'PayPal/SOAP/Client.php';
PayPal/SOAP/Client.php:// $Id: Client.php,v 1.1.1.1 2006/02/19
PayPal/SOAP/WSDL.php: //require_once 'PayPal/SOAP/Client.php
```

It's for sure that there are no more files in my app that could include Client.php.

Javi

Regards

Javi

Comment: Is the file being `include()`ed twice?  Either be very careful to include() it only once, or switch to `include_once()`.

Comment: Are you actually changing the name of the class or just the file name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the file with class is included twice, that's why it always get's redeclared even if you change the name. Look for duplicate includes or always use `require_once()` instead of `require()`.

Run this command to find places, where file is included:

```
grep -R 'Client.php' *
```

Another way to debug, is to temporaterly replace all contents of Client.php with this:

```
<pre>
<?php
    print_r(debug_backtrace());
?>
</pre>
<hr />
```

It will show you from where file gets included.